# Manually Computing the Determinant of a n×n Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

My teacher has asked us to compute the determinant of a 6×6 matrix manually. The matrix is of the following form, where the alphabets denote constants:

\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0&0&i&j\\
c&d&0&0&k&l\\
0&0&5&2&0&0\\
0&0&7&6&0&0\\
e&f&0&0&m&n\\
g&h&0&0&o&p\end{pmatrix}

Is there a quick way to manually solve a matrix that looks like this? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Expansion by minors (or Laplace expansion) is the way I know.  There are a lot of zeros, so that simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

Using two successive linear combinations of columns: $\:C_3\leftarrow C_3-C_4$, then $C_4\leftarrow C_4-6C_3$, and expanding along the relevant row/column, you finally  obtain a $4\times 4$ determinant:
$$\det =16\begin{vmatrix}a&b&i&j\\c&d&k&l\\e&f&m&n\\g&h&o&p\end{vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You get $a\begin{vmatrix}d&0&0&k&l\\0&5&2&0&0\\0&7&6&0&0\\f&0&0&m&n\\h&0&0&o&p\end{vmatrix}-b\begin{vmatrix}c&0&0&k&l\\0&5&2&0&0\\0&7&6&0&0\\0&0&0&m&n\\g&0&0&o&p\end{vmatrix}+i\begin{vmatrix}c&d&0&0&l\\0&0&5&2&0\\0&0&7&6&0\\e&f&0&0&n\\g&h&0&0&p\end{vmatrix}-j\begin{vmatrix}c&d&0&0&k\\0&0&5&2&0\\0&0&7&6&0\\e&f&0&0&m\\g&h&0&0&o\end{vmatrix}$ etc...

The first determinant above is $d\begin{vmatrix}5&2&0&0\\7&6&0&0\\0&0&m&n\\0&0&o&p\end{vmatrix}-k\begin{vmatrix}0&5&2&0\\0&7&6&0\\f&0&0&n\\h&0&0&p\end{vmatrix}+l\begin{vmatrix}0&5&2&0\\0&7&6&0\\f&0&0&m\\h&0&0&o\end{vmatrix}=16[d(mp-on)-k(fp-nh)+l(fo-mh)]$.